# Issues with Inserting Additional Data into User Session Using NextAuth in Next.js

Tags: session, next.js, callback, jwt, next-auth

I'm experiencing a problem with inserting additional data into the user session in a Next.js application using NextAuth. Specifically, I'm trying to add data fetched from an API to the session, but it's not working as expected. Here's the relevant part of my NextAuth configuration:

```
callbacks: {
signIn: async ({ user, account, profile, email, credentials, session }) => {
    return true;
},
jwt: async ({ token, user, trigger, session }) => {
    if (user) {
        const lab = await fetchData('/api/lab/list/' + user.email)
        token.role = user.role
        token.user = user
        token.lab = lab
    }
    return token
},
session: async ({ session, token, user }) => {
    session.user.role = token.role
    session.user.id = token.user.id
    session.user.lab = token.lab
    return session;
},
```

},

In the jwt callback, I'm fetching additional user data with fetchData('/api/lab/list/' + user.email) and attempting to add this data to the token. However, the lab variable is returning null, and as a result, token.lab is not being set correctly. This leads to session.user.lab being undefined in the session callback.

I have separately tested the fetchData function, and it works correctly, returning the expected data. Therefore, I'm puzzled as to why lab is returning null in this context.

Could someone help me understand why this is happening and how to successfully insert additional data into the user session using NextAuth? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem: in the fetchData function, I was using Axios with a relative path. By switching to an absolute path, everything was resolved. It seems that the issue is that API calls must be made with absolute paths within the NextAuth API, unlike on the client pages. If anyone has anything more to add, I would be more than grateful.